# NodeJS Axios setting header in axios request generates " Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char"

Tags: reactjs, axios, request, header, jsx

It doesn't matter what I set the header to, axios still generates an error.

Code:

```
app.use(`/a/prx/*`, function(req, res) {
    const path = req.originalUrl.split(`/`).splice(-1).toString(); 
    var options = {
        url: `https://api.example.com/apis/${path}/`,
        method: req.method,
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla"
            // really, I'd like to use req.headers["user-agent"]
        }
    };
    axios(options)
        .then((responseFromServer2) => {
            // do good stuff
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.send(`ERROR: ${err}`);
        });
});
```

I'd like to set the user-agent header to the original user-agent for tracking purposes but doing so generates an error.